# Print vector with more decimal numbers

Tags: python, vector

When outputting values for a `mathutils.Vector` and `mathutils.Matrix`, there's normally only 4 decimals printed out. Is there a way to output more decimals or would I have to do it manually like this?

```
print("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f" % (myVector.x, myVector.y, myVector.z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`str` and `repr`**

What you see in a print statement is the classes `__str__` method, or how to represent the instance as a string, which as mentioned prints to 4 decimal places.

```
>>> str(C.object.location)
'<Vector (0.0000, 1.6400, 0.0000)>'
```

The representation, defined on class as `def __repr__(self)` result

```
>>> repr(C.object.location)
'Vector((0.0, 1.6399999856948853, 0.0))'
```

Gives us the values we would get from printing individuals.

```
>>> C.object.location.y
1.6399999856948853
```

and is what you see for result echoed in the python console.

```
>>> C.object.location
Vector((0.0, 1.6399999856948853, 0.0))
```

Similarly for matrix

```
>>> str(C.object.matrix_world)
'<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.9893, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)\n            ( 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 1.6400)\n            (-0.1461, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)\n            ( 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>'

>>> repr(C.object.matrix_world)
'Matrix(((0.9892723560333252, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),\n        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.6399999856948853),\n        (-0.1460830420255661, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),\n        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))'

>>> print(repr(C.object.matrix_world))
Matrix(((0.9892723560333252, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.6399999856948853),
        (-0.1460830420255661, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

To have 7 decimal places for each the suggestion in question is a good as any.

```
>>> print("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f" % C.object.location[:])
0.0000000, 1.6400000, 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @batFINGER!